# How to use patterndb in syslog-ng

Tags: linux, unix, syslog, syslog-ng

```
syslog-ng.conf

https://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/opensource-logging-system/features/pattern-db

@define logfileName "/apps/syslog-ng/etc/testing.log"
@define Pattern1 ".*Exception.*"

source s_app1.conf { file("`logfileName`" flags(no-parse)  follow-freq(1)); };

#Edit here below vars
#InstanceName in each template  ( need to start with $HOST.)
#EventName (as numbered ) in each template line. 
#change <first section> as required for severity.
#186 -> Critical (critical)
#187 -> Major    (error)
#188 -> Minor    (warning)

parser pattern_db {
            db_parser(
                file("/apps/syslog-ng/etc/syslog-ng-patterndb-master/applications/openssh/example.xml")
            );
            };

            parser t_app1.conf_1 {
            db_parser(
                file("/apps/syslog-ng/etc/syslog-ng-patterndb-master/applications/openssh/example.xml")
            );
            };

template t_app1.conf_1
{
    template ("<186><$ISODATE>[HostName=$HOST][ClassName=Application][InstanceName=$HOST/BoB/app2-l1][EventName=`Pattern1`][LogFileName=`logfileName`][$MSG] ${SSH_USERNAME}; ${SSH_CLIENT_ADDRESS} \n");
    template_escape(no);
};
destination d_app1.conf_1 { syslog("10.54.20.98" transport("udp") port(514)  template(t_app1.conf_1)); };



filter f_app1.conf_1 { message("`Pattern1`" flags("utf8" "ignore-case") ); };



log { source(s_app1.conf); filter(f_app1.conf_1); destination(d_app1.conf_1); flags(final); };
```

my patterndb xml

```
example.xml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<patterndb version="3" pub_date="2010-04-15">
    <ruleset name='ssh' id='123456678'>
        <pattern>ssh</pattern>
            <rules>
                <rule provider='me' id='182437592347598' class='system'>
                    <patterns>
                        <pattern>Accepted @ESTRING:SSH.AUTH_METHOD: @for @ESTRING:SSH_USERNAME: @from @ESTRING:SSH_CLIENT_ADDRESS: @port @NUMBER:SSH_PORT_NUMBER:@ ssh2</pattern>
                    </patterns>
                    <examples>
                        <example>
                            <test_message program="ssh">Accepted password for sampleuser from 10.50.0.247 port 42156 ssh2</test_message>
                            <test_values>
                                <test_value name="SSH.AUTH_METHOD">password</test_value>
                                <test_value name="SSH_USERNAME">sampleuser</test_value>
                                <test_value name="SSH_CLIENT_ADDRESS">10.50.0.247</test_value>
                                <test_value name="SSH_PORT_NUMBER">42156</test_value>
                            </test_values>
                       </example>
                    </examples>
                </rule>
            </rules>
    </ruleset>
</patterndb>
```

I am trying to use patterndb with syslog-ng by going  through their offiical  blog,i am able to install and use syslog but not patterndb as there is no installation guide which describes how to use patterndb.if anyone has used patterndb with syslog on linux system please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can find information in the [official documentation of syslog-ng patterndb](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/chapter-patterndb.html).

Basically, you want to [create a patterndb file](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-patterndb-schemes.html) (you can find [sample patterndb files on github](https://github.com/balabit/syslog-ng-patterndb), and also in this [blogpost](https://czanik.blogs.balabit.com/2016/03/making-sense-of-zorp-firewall-logs-using-syslog-ng/)), and [use it in your syslog-ng configuration to parse the log messages](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/configuring-pattern-databases.html).

Then, depending on how or what you have parsed, you can use the results in your destination template, or for filtering, or many other things.

Can you describe what and why you'd like to parse?

Comment: consider i want to parse this common message "Accepted password for sampleuser from 10.50.0.247 port 42156 ssh2" ,so for this i just need a xml file which contanins patterndb xml ?

Comment: In patterndb, the xml file contains the rules that parse the messages. For each message you want to parse, you'll need a matching rule (one rule can match multiple different messages, depending on the messages). To parse the above SSH login message, you need only a rule for this message. You can find sample rules for SSH here: https://github.com/balabit/syslog-ng-patterndb/blob/master/applications/openssh/sshd.xml

Comment: hi robert ,can you check whether conf file correct or not?

Comment: Hi, you have defined the pattern database in your config, but you are not actually using it in the log path. Try something like this):

log { source(s_app1.conf); parser (t_app1.conf_1); filter(f_app1.conf_1); destination(d_app1.conf_1); flags(final); };

Comment: hi robert, can you help my friend with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319887/correlation-using-patterndb-and-syslog